# How to migrate `base R` location plot to `ggplot2` and avoid `for` loop?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm interested in visualizing the location of certain words in sentences. Say I have 500 sentences between 3-5 words long and want to visualize the location of word `A` in each sentence:

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
w1 <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 1000, replace = TRUE) 
w2 <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 1000, replace = TRUE)
w3 <- sample(LETTERS[1:6], 1000, replace = TRUE)
w4 <- sample(c(NA,LETTERS[1:7]), 1000, replace = TRUE)
w5 <- sample(c(NA,LETTERS[1:8]), 1000, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(
  position = rep(1:5, each = 1000),                       # position of word in sentence
  word = c(w1, w2, w3, w4, w5)                            # the words in the sentences
)
```

I can produce the location plot in `base R`. But the code involves a very slow `for` loop and does not have the aesthetic qualities of `ggplot2`. So how can the same type of visualization be produced **faster and in `ggplot2`**?

[image]

This is the code that produces the location plot in `base R`:

```
# Plot dimensions:
x <- rep(1:5, 100)
y <- 1:500

# Plot parameters:
par(mar=c(2,1.5,1,1.5), par(xpd = T))

# Plot:
plot(y ~ x, type = "n", frame = F, axes = F, ylab="", xlab="", 
     main="Location of word 'A' in sentences", cex.main=0.9)
axis(1, at=seq(1:5), labels=c("w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w5"), cex.axis=0.9)

# Legend:
legend(2.25, 530, c("A", "other", "NA"), fill=c("blue", "orange", "black"), 
       horiz = T, cex = 0.7, bty = "n", border = "white")

# For loop to print 'A' as color in positions:
for(i in unique(df$position)){
  text(i, 1:500, "__________", cex = 1,
       col = ifelse(df[df$position==i,]$word=="A", "blue", "orange"))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example using geom_segment, and then with a conditional aesthetic.

I am using ggh4x for the truncated axis.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggh4x)

df <- 
  df %>% group_by(position) %>%mutate(index = row_number())

ggplot(df, aes( color = word=="A")) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = position-.4, xend = position+.4, 
                   y = index, yend = index),
               key_glyph= "rect") +
  scale_color_manual(name = NULL, 
                     values=c(`TRUE` = "blue", `FALSE` = "orange"),
                     labels = c(`TRUE` = "A", `FALSE` = "other"),
                     na.value="black")+ 
  guides(x = "axis_truncated") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:5, labels = paste0("w", 1:5))+
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
        legend.position = "top") +
  labs( y = NULL, x = NULL, title = "Location of A")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice job. What I'd also like to see is the location of `NA`values. How can that be added?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann add na.value to scale_color... see update

Comment: Thanks a lot.One last question: how could the plot title be set **above** the plot and how could the dashes to the left of the labels be replaced by filled squares?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann see update. - easiest to use rectangular key glyphs. You can change the size with themes setting. for the legend, set this in theme(). I have removed the legend title and replaced with a plot title, because this is easier to place separately

Answer (score 2):

Here's an initial attempt. (I'm not quite clear, are you looking to show just the first 500 of the 1000 sentences?)

My approach here is to first summarize the data in terms of contiguous sections that are A / other / NA. This way, the plot area is filled exactly without needing to tweak line thickness, and it should plot more quickly by reducing the number of plotted elements.

```
library(dplyr)
df_plot <- df %>%
  mutate(A_spots = case_when(word == "A" ~ "A",
                             word != "A" ~ "other",
                             TRUE ~ "NA")) %>%
  group_by(position) %>%
  mutate(col_chg = A_spots != lag(A_spots, default = ""),
         group_num = cumsum(col_chg)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  count(position, group_num, A_spots)
  
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_plot, aes(position, n, fill = A_spots, group = group_num)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = NULL, breaks = 1:5,   #stolen from @tjebo's answer
                 labels = paste0("w", 1:5))+
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("A" = "blue","other" = "orange", "NA" = "black")) +
  labs(title = "Location of word 'A' in sentences") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]